# Woocommerce Get Product Values by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to get Product Data on custom Template By product ID, right now i have this code to get Product Title.

```
$productId = 164;
echo $p_title = get_the_title( $productId );
```

looking for Short Description, Price, Product Image, Product Url, Product Brand. Or might be loop will be better but that loop should work with product static ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You would probably be better served by creating a new product object.

```
$productId = 164;
$product = wc_get_product( $productId );
echo $product->get_title();
echo $product->get_price_html();
```

Note, that the short description is merely the post's `post_excerpt`. If using outside of the loop (where `$post` is automatically defined) then you would need to get the post directly.

```
$post = get_post( $productId );

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
```

or alternatively, if you've already defined the product object you could do

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->post->post_excerpt );
```

since the WooCommerce product class will automatically define the `$product->post` property with `get_post()`.

`apply_filters()` means that functions can be attached at this point to modify the content of `$product->post->post_content`. At a minimum, I know that `wpautop()` is attached to the `woocommerce_short_description` filter to create paragraph breaks.

Comment: i did not understand how to apply filters here for the excerpt, also i need url

Comment: if you can expalin little bit more about the post_excerpt for the product using product id. that will be great

Comment: I'm not sure what else you needed to know, but I've tried to elaborate a little.

Comment: Thanks your are great

Comment: If this answers your question, can you accept the answer?

Comment: how does $product->get_title(); will work as wc_get_product is not a class?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla `wc_get_product` is not a class. It's a wrapper function that uses the `WC_Product_Factory` class to retrieve the correct product class depending on the product type. So assuming the `$productId ` is actually a product post type then `$product = wc_get_product( $productId );` will return a product class object.