# Accessing WC_Product protected data in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, class, object, woocommerce

I have this answer for reference: [Woocommerce Get Product Values by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165402/woocommerce-get-product-values-by-id/35165541#35165541) … It is about the function `wc_get_product()` that returns protected data.

Where are the getter methods defined for that function? 
How can i access the protected data inside `wc_get_product()`?

[This Answer thread](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product.html) is telling that `WC_Product_Factory` class is being used.  Can this class be extended to access the protected data inside `wc_get_product()`?

The `wc_get_product()` seems to be a function, but how does it return an object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `wc_get_product( $product_id)` function gives the `WC_Product` instance object *(from a product ID)* where data can be accessed with all available [`WC_Product` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) and `WC_Product` sub-classes depending on the product type:

```
// Get the instance of the WC_Product Object
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id);

// Using `WC_Product` methods examples to get specific related data values:

$product_type  = $product->get_type(); // product Type
$product_id    = $product->get_id(); // product ID
$product_name  = $product->get_name(); // product name
$product_sku   = $product->get_sku(); // product SKU
$product_price = $product->get_price(); // product price

// And so on…

// The raw display of the object protected data (Just for testing)
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $product ); echo '</pre>';
```

You can unprotect the data using the [`WC_Data` method `get_data()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_data) that will give you an accessible array of the data:

```
// Get the instance of the WC_Product Object
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id);

// Get the accessible array of product properties:
$data = $product->get_data();

// get specific related data values:

$product_id    = $data['id']; // product ID
$product_name  = $data['name']; // product name
$product_sku   = $data['sku']; // product SKU
$product_price = $data['price']; // product price

// And so on…

// The raw display of the unprotected data array (Just for testing)
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $data ); echo '</pre>';
```

> For specific **custom meta data** you can use the [`WC_Data` method `get_meta()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_meta). So if the custom meta key is for example **`_custom_height`** you will use:
>
> ```
> $custom_product_height = $product->get_meta( '_custom_height' );
> ```

Official Woocommerce API Documentation:

- [`WC_Product` list of methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)
- [`WC_Product_External` list of methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_External.html)
- [`WC_Product_Grouped` list of methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Grouped.html)
- [`WC_Product_Simple` list of methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Simple.html)
- [`WC_Product_Variable` list of methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variable.html)
- [`WC_Product_Variation` list of methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html)
- [`WC_Data` list of methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html)

Comment: Thank you Loic ..Clear and perfect as always.

Comment: Loic can you tell me how to use attributes and variations with custom product type?

Comment: @booota It's  complicated as you need to extend in a correct way the related required WooCommerce Classes, depending on your custom product requirements… So This is out StackOverFlow scope.

Comment: Thanks for the Documentation section. SEO of woocommerce apis is worst :(